# How to set aws proxy host to Spark config

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, amazon-s3

Any idea how to set aws proxy host, and region to spark session or spark context.

I am able to set in aws javasdk code, and it is working fine.

```
      ClientConfiguration clientConfig = new ClientConfiguration();
      clientConfig.setProxyHost("aws-proxy-qa.xxxxx.organization.com");
        clientConfig.setProxyPort(8099));

      AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard()
        .withRegion(getAWSRegion(Regions.US_WEST_2)
        .withClientConfiguration(clientConfig) //Setting aws proxy host
```

Can help me to set same thing to spark context ( both region and proxy) since i am reading a s3 file which is different region from emr region.

Answer (score 1):

based on fs.s3a.access.key and fs.s3a.secret.key region will be automatically determined.

just like other s3 properties
set this to sparkConf

```
/**
      * example getSparkSessionForS3
      * @return
      */
    def getSparkSessionForS3():SparkSession = {
  val conf = new SparkConf()
    .setAppName("testS3File")
    .set("spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.impl", "org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem")
    .set("spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.endpoint", "yourendpoint")
    .set("spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.connection.maximum", "200")
    .set("spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.fast.upload", "true")
    .set("spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.connection.establish.timeout", "500")
    .set("spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.connection.timeout", "5000")
    .set("spark.hadoop.mapreduce.fileoutputcommitter.algorithm.version", "2")
    .set("spark.hadoop.com.amazonaws.services.s3.enableV4", "true")
    .set("spark.hadoop.com.amazonaws.services.s3.enforceV4", "true")
    .set("spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.proxy.host","yourhost") 
  val spark = SparkSession
    .builder()
    .config(conf)
    .getOrCreate()
  spark
}
```

Comment: Looks good, but (a) you don't need that fs.s3a.impl one and (b) I don't think those com.amazonaws options are picked up in the S3A client. The hadoop s3a docs cover their switch to use the v4 signing (which will become mandatory soon)